# Show direction kind for operations in magicdraw

Tags: magic-draw

Im using magicdraw sysml to document software functionality. In my BDD i have a block, representinge a software component. To document the functions exposed by the compenent, im using "operations". When listing the operations, i would like the parameters of the operation to show the direction of the parameter. "in/out/inout/return".

I have tried using "behavior" and under Symbol properties i'm able to select "Show direction kind". This does work, but only for behavior, not operations.

Answer (score 0):

I found it under Symbol Properties, when selecting "All" instead of "Standard"